# Configure theintern for unit testing only

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

I am trying to configure intern (https://theintern.github.io) for unit testing.

Here is my configuration

```
define([ 'intern' ], function (intern) {
  // Return configuration for intern tests
  var config =  {
    basePath: '../',
    loaderOptions: {
      packages: [
                { name: 'app', location: 'app' },
                { name: 'jquery', location: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery' },
                { name: 'underscore', location: 'bower_components/underscore/underscore' },
                { name: 'backbone', location: 'bower_components/backbone/backbone' }
      ]
    },
    suites: [
      'tests/mymodule'
    ],
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules|bower_components|test)\//,
    loaders: {
      'host-node': 'requirejs',
      'host-browser': 'bower_components/requirejs/require.js',
    },
    reporters: [
      {id:'Console'}
    ]      

  };
  return config;
});
```

And I am receiving following error

```
> intern-runner config=tests/intern

Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
Transformation error; return original code
TypeError: SourceNode is not a constructor
    at toSourceNodeWhenNeeded (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:535:20)
    at generateIdentifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:866:16)
    at CodeGenerator.Identifier (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2244:20)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.MemberExpression (C:\repo\\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:1910:28)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
    at CodeGenerator.UpdateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2009:26)
    at CodeGenerator.generateExpression (C:\repo\my-app\node_modules\escodegen\escodegen.js:2427:28)
ReferenceError: __cov_YGSj0arNmIBnXUo5NAKQbw is not defined
  at Object.<anonymous>  <node_modules\digdug\NullTunnel.js:9:1>
  at Module._compile  <module.js:570:32>
  at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js]  <node_modules\istanbul\lib\hook.js:107:24>
  at Module.load  <module.js:487:32>
  at tryModuleLoad  <module.js:446:12>
  at Function.Module._load  <module.js:438:3>
  at Module.require  <module.js:497:17>
  at require  <internal\module.js:20:19>
  at Object.load  <node_modules\intern\browser_modules\dojo\node.ts:56:11>
  at Object.<anonymous>  <node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1347:28>
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

How can I configure theintern only for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like modules in `node_modules` are being instrumented for code coverage (the bit about "__cov_YGSj0arNmIBnXUo5NAKQbw is not defined" is coverage-related).

Since you're running on Windows, try removing the `\/` from the end of `excludeInstrumentation`:

```
excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules|bower_components|test)/,
```